# How to post List<Model> using partial view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Main question: Is it possible to post a list of model using partial view in `asp.net mvc`?

Example: Lets assume a `class` as `Student` having 2 properties(RollNo(`int`) and Name(`string`))

```
public class Student 
{ 
     public int RollNo { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller having post method where I want list of students from partial view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostListOfStudents(List<Student> lstStudents)
{
    //some logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure you can.

Here is partial view model:

```
@model List<Student>
```

You only have to iterate over your list model like below:

```
@Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post)
{
    if (Model != null) 
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
       {
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Name)
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].RollNo)
       }
       <input type="submit" value="Post Data" /> 
    }
}
```

You can pass the list of `Students` in partial view as below:

```
@Html.Partial("_partialview", listOfStudents);
```

Then at your post action you will get the list of student. Just be sure to use proper  input extension methods in your case.